# Read the text of an Editor inside the DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a CollectionView with an Editor inside the DataTemplate. Through a button I would like to be able to read the text inside. How can I do?

```
    <CollectionView 
        x:Name="CollectionEditIcon" 
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
        Margin="10"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        SelectionMode="None">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" Span="1" VerticalItemSpacing="5" HorizontalItemSpacing="5"/>
         </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
         <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <Grid>
                      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                       </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                         <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                         <RowDefinition Height="27"/>
                       </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                       <Editor x:Name="EditName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="16" MaxLength="40" IsReadOnly="True" IsVisible="{Binding Edit}"/>
                       <ImageButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Source="IconEdit.png" Clicked="Edit_Clicked" />
                   </Grid>
              </DataTemplate>
          </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
   </CollectionView>
```

With a button I can make the Editor visible, but then I can't go on

```
private void Edit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var button = sender as ImageButton;
            var model = button.BindingContext as IconDiary;
            model.Edit = true;
        }
```

Comment: your editor is bound to the "id" property, to just refer to that property of your model

Comment: It already has a value, but the user has the ability to edit the text. when it is modified, how do i read it?

Comment: when you bind an Entry to a property, the property will be updated when the user types in the Entry.  That's the entire purpose of data binding, to tie together the data and the UI

Comment: I would like to take that text and use it to insert my object into an ObservableCollection, which has a string property that I would like to be what the user typed

Comment: Yes.  As I have explained, repeatedly, that text should be in the id property that Entry is bound to.

Comment: yes, but the user can modify it, so then I would like to insert the new value in the id property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Editor` is bound to the `id` property of the model.  That means whatever the user enters in the `Editor` should be reflected in the model automatically

```
<Editor x:Name="EditName" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding id}" TextColor="Gray" FontSize="16" MaxLength="40" IsReadOnly="True" IsVisible="{Binding Edit}"/>


private void Edit_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var button = sender as ImageButton;
    var model = button.BindingContext as IconDiary;
    model.Edit = true;

    // the id property should contain the text the user entered
    var text = model.id;
}
```